# Gitlab: Get ancestor groups of a project via Python API bindings

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

Im using https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab to automate several tasks over multiple Gitlab repositories / projects. This worked fine up until now: I have a Gitlab project and want to get its parent group. According to https://docs.gitlab.com/13.12/ee/api/projects.html#list-a-projects-groups this should be possible, but I cannot find that functionality in the Python bindings.

Am I missing something? Is that feature missing in the Python bindings? Does anybody know a workaround, that does not force me to got to "pure" REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the code it looks like the feature is just missing, but I figured out a workaround:

```
p = ... project instance ...
path = "/projects/%s/groups" % p.get_id()
groups = p.manager.gitlab.http_get(path)
```